# Publishing subprojects with the Gradle-Artifactory plugin

Tags: maven, gradle, publish, artifactory

I have the following multi-project Gradle build:

```
myapp/
    myapp-client/
        build.gradle
        src/** (omitted for brevity)
    myapp-shared/
        build.gradle
        src/** (omitted for brevity)
    myapp-server
        build.gradle
        src/** (omitted for brevity)
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

Where `myapp/build.gradle` looks like:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // My local/private Artifactory
            url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/myapp-snapshots"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile (
            'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7'
        )
    }
}
```

And where each of the 3 subproject Gradle files are currently very simple:

```
dependencies {
    compile (
        'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    )
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- When I run `gradle clean build -Pversion=0.1.5` from the parent `myapp` directory, I want all three subprojects to be built with a version of 0.1.5; hence `myapp-client-0.1.5.jar`, `myapp-shared-0.1.5.jar` and `myapp-server-0.1.5.jar`. Currently my build already does this, however...
- If the client and shared JARs build successfully, I also want them published to my private Artifactory repo. (I don't wish to publish the server JAR).

The most compact code I've been able to find and test/confirm for publishing a Gradle-built JAR to Artifactory is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "admin"
                password = "12345"
            }
            name = "maven-main-cache"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

repositories {
    add buildscript.repositories.getByName("maven-main-cache")
    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/myapp-snapshots"
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'myapp-snapshots'
            username = "admin"
            password = "12345"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this snippet inside a test `build.gradle` project, and run `gradle artifactoryPublish`, it correctly publishes my JAR to Artifactory.

My question: **How can I add this snippet to my project such that running `gradle clean build` from the parent dir, on success, produces client and shared JARs being published to Artifactory?**

Although not ideal, I would be *willing* to make the publishing a separate, second step if its not possible to do all this in one fell swoop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `artifactory` plugin is the right way to do.
You need to apply it to `allprojects` and disable the deployment on the top-level project with `artifactoryPublish.skip=true`.
You can find a fully working example of a project much similar to yours [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/4/gradle-example/build.gradle#start-of-content).

By default `build` is not dependent on `artifactoryPublish` ,so you need to run `gradle build artifactoryPublish` to upload the jars. The reason is you might want to run a lot of builds until you decide to upload something. You can establish the dependency by configuring `build` to be depending on `artifactoryPublish`:

```
build(dependsOn: 'artifactoryPublish')
```

Comment: @Adil I think JBaruch is referencing https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples.  Here's the 4.x version https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/4/gradle-example/build.gradle#start-of-content

Comment: Any clue why a multi project would skip jar publication when the same code in a single project works?  Can't figure out why its skiping

Comment: what I've come across is that FIRST Artifactory plugin is configured on root, and only THEN are subprojects configured by gradle, thus their properties like `group` and `version` are not visible to Artifactory configuration. What is the proper way to work around this ? [JFrog example][1] uses version from `gradle.properties`, and group name set from root project, which I would prefer not to do.


  [1]: https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/gradle-cache-example

Comment: Properties is the way to go.